# SSRS Report with Oracle database performance problems

Tags: oracle, reporting-services

I am creating a report using SQL Server Reporting Services which is selecting data from an Oracle database.  The report is working but it takes a long time to generate (~75 secs).  I have the following very simple query in my report:

```
SELECT  
(SELECT   COUNT(*)  
   FROM   CALL  
  WHERE   trunc(start_time) >= :Begin_Date 
    AND   trunc(finish_time) <=  :End_Date) AS total_calls,
(SELECT   COUNT(*)  
   FROM   CALL  
  WHERE   DISCONNECT = 'T' 
    AND   trunc(start_time) >= :Begin_Date 
    AND   trunc(finish_time) <=  :End_Date) AS transfered_calls,
(SELECT   COUNT(*)  
   FROM   CALL  
  WHERE   DISCONNECT = 'H' 
    AND   trunc(start_time) >=  :Begin_Date 
    AND   trunc(finish_time) <=  :End_Date) AS hangups
FROM DUAL
```

Now I can execute this query in Oracle using SQLPlus* (with the dates filled in of course) and it executes in about 8 seconds.   When I try to execute the same query in the SSRS report it takes 75 seconds to generate.  My concern is that I need to add lots more queries to complete the report and if it takes so long just to generate this basic version of the report, there is no way the finished report will work.  How can I improve performance of the report?  Any ideas?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You could certainly improve the performance by only hitting the `CALL` table once

```
SELECT COUNT(*) total_calls,
       SUM(CASE WHEN disconnect = 'T'
                THEN 1
                ELSE 0
             END) transferred_calls,
       SUM(CASE WHEN disconnect = 'H'
                THEN 1
                ELSE 0
              END) hangups
  FROM call
 WHERE trunc(start_time)  >= :Begin_Date
   AND trunc(finish_time) <= :End_Date
```

Additionally, a function-based index on `TRUNC(start_time)` and `TRUNC(finish_time)` would likely be helpful (assuming the parameters you are passing in are restricting the set of rows being considered to a relatively small subset of the rows in the table).

As for the performance difference between SSRS and SQL*Plus, are the query plans the same?  Can you trace the SSRS report to see what it is waiting on?

Comment: +1 I would go with this solution first.  It is simple and how you SHOULD be designing your query.  If you are still having performance issues then start looking into other systems issues (like indexes) and maybe creating views or stored procs.

Comment: +1 If the table already has an index on start_time and end_time then the query should be able to make use of it if the where clause is amended to `where start_time >= :Begin_Date and finish time < to_date(:End_Date)+1` .

Answer (score 0):

A couple suggestions.  First make sure you have your tables properly indexed so you can utilize Oracle Optimizer.  When I do these kinds of reports I find that if I create a view that gets the data I need it runs better.  You can also create a stored procedure to do the same.  I have used both and I get great results from them.  Additionally, using embedded select statements with in the SELECT clause is never a great idea.  If you can find a way to remove these (like calling a function instead) you will probably see some additional performance gains.